# Incremental fetching data for every half an hour from Oracle Database

Tags: oracle

I have a table which has 150 Billion data,

1) First I need to fetch historical data from the table and load into target with high performance(I have indexes on few columns). I have tried with below queries  like

```
select * 
  from Historical_table
```

and

```
select /*+PARALLEL(a,8)*/ a.* 
  from Historical_table a
```

It's taking almost an hour time but no result.

2) And I need to run incremental data which fetches every half an hour updated data from the table

eg: I have a time stamp column if I'm fetching the data at 4 pm it should fetch only the data from 3:30 PM-4:00 PM data and 
if I'm running at 4:30 PM it has to fetch the data from 4:00 PM-4:30 PM

and this incremental query should run in less than 15 min. I'm looking for the better performance query.

Could someone please help me on this

Thanks.

Comment: Can you run a execution plan of your query and post your results?

Comment: Which table has the 150B rows?

Comment: Have you considered using Materialized views to do this? It might be simpler, plus you could possibly get it to refresh fast on commit, meaning whenever someone adds a row, it automatically gets added to the mview.